# flutter/dart: draw 2d graph with gradient interpolation between data points

Tags: python, matplotlib, flutter, graph, shader

I'd like to draw a 2D time series in color with flutter.

### Goal

Obviously, it's different from 1D data in that along the y-axis I have a vector of **discrete data points** at each x, but the color graph must be continuous. So I'd love to use color gradients between these data points to present **a continuous heat map**.

The end result would look like a spectrogram
[image]

With Python's matplotlib, this would be a simple `imshow()` call.

### Reference

From this question: [How to do a Gradient effect from topLeft to botttomRgiht in Flutter Shader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59679564/how-to-do-a-gradient-effect-from-topleft-to-botttomrgiht-in-flutter-shader)

I learned that I could use flutter's shader to create color gradients. That's fine.

### Problem

But it seems to me that I would need **hundreds of shaders between the data points** in order to draw dynamic gradients I want. The y-vector could be as big as 1000 to 2000 data points at each moment.

Is there a simpler way to achieve what I want, such as using as few shaders as possible?

Comment: How about this: https://vocalability.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/spectrogram.jpg

Comment: To whoever commented on this question: I don't know why, but I seemed to have erased your comment after posting using iOS StackOverflow app (bug?). This is so bizarre!  Sorry. If you could post back that would be great.

Comment: Can you share how you made spectrogram in flutter

Comment: @kakyo Any luck with this?